# ¿Cómo comparar dos objetos dentro de un ArrayList? (Java)

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Estoy intentando realizar un `ArrayList` con `x` productos `(Agua,Chocolate,Cartuchera,etc..)` Y quiero saber como comparar ambos objetos para saber cual es mas caro. *(La superclase es producto)*

```
ArrayList<Producto> lista = new ArrayList<Producto>();
 // Objeto Agua
Bebida b1 = new Bebida();
b1.setNombre("Agua");
b1.setPrecio(40);

// Objeto Chocolate
Alimento a1 = new Alimento();
a1.setNombre("Chocolate");
a1.setPrecio(55);

// Objeto Cartuchera
Util u1 = new Util();
u1.setNombre("Cartuchera");
u1.setPrecio(70);

lista.add(b1);
lista.add(a1);
lista.add(u1);
```

¿Como puedo comparar su precio? quiero que quede así:

> Articulo mas caro:Cartuchera.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Opino **CASI** como el resto de compañeros que te han dado esta respuesta:

```
Producto pro = new Producto();
for (Producto produc: lista) 
    if(produc.getPrecio()>pro.getPrecio()) pro = produc;
        System.out.println("El mayor es  : " + pro.getNombre());
```

Pero si haces esto te va a fallar ya que creas un producto y no lo inicializas e intentas acceder a uno de sus métodos, con lo cual si intentas hacer

```
    if(produc.getPrecio()>pro.getPrecio())
```

Te va a devolver un NullPointerException. Para que esto te funciones tienes que hacer

```
    Producto pro = new Producto();
    pro = lista.get(0);    //Igualas el producto al primer elemento de la lista y ya puedes empezar a hacer las comparaciones.
    for (Producto produc: lista) 
        if(produc.getPrecio()>pro.getPrecio()) pro = produc;

    System.out.println("El mayor es  : " + pro.getNombre());
```

Comment: Me sirvio!
Me podrias explicar por que da un NullPointerException?

Comment: Por supuesto. Cuando haces Producto pro = new Producto(); estás creando un producto, hasta ahí está bien, pero no le asignas valores, así que cuando intentas recuperar el valor te da null. Si no quieres igualarlo al primer elemento (que está bien hecho) crea el producto y asígnale un precio (-1 para que sea el menor de todos seguro) y un nombre ("") ya que sino te dará el error al hacer el getNombre()

Comment: En el caso de pro.getPrecio() la primera ocasión no debería marcar NullPointerException, ya que el atributo **precio tiene un valor entero, su valor por default sería 0** . Me es un poco extraño que suceda eso @Ale.

Answer (score 5):

Hay muchas opciones para realizar esto , plantearé algunas.

- Iterando sobre la Lista de elementos

  ```
  Producto pro = new Producto();
  for (Producto produc: lista) 
       if(produc.getPrecio()>pro.getPrecio()) pro = produc;
  System.out.println("El mayor es  : " + pro.getNombre());
  ```
- Ordenando la Lista de mayor a Menor y luego obtener el primer elemento

  ```
  Collections.sort(lista,new Comparator<Producto>() {
      public int compare(Producto o1, Producto o2) {
          return Integer.compare(o2.getPrecio(), o1.getPrecio());
      }
  });
  System.out.println("El mayor es   ; " + lista.get(0).getNombre());
  ```
- Empleando `Comparator` *(Java8)*

  ```
  Producto mayor = Collections.max(lista, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getPrecio()));
  System.out.println("El mayor es   ; " + mayor.getNombre());
  ```

Answer (score 3):

```
Producto producto_conMayorPrecio = new Producto(); 

for (Producto producto : list)
{
    if (producto.getPrecio() > producto_conMayorPrecio.getPrecio())
       producto_conMayorPrecio = producto;
}
```

Creo que con eso puedes mejorarlo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, lo que tendrías que hacer es declarar dos variables: una para almacenar el precio y otra para almacenar el nombre del producto más caro. 
Estas dos variables las inicializas con el primer elemento de tu `ArrayList`, para tener algo con qué comparar. 
Después lo único que tienes que hacer recorrer los elementos e ir comparando los precios del que actualmente es el más caro con el precio del elemento que estás recorriendo. 
No tengo IDE para java, pero espero escribirlo bien sin compilar:

```
string nombreProducto;
int precioProducto;
if(list.size() > 0){
    nombreProducto = list.get(0).getNombre();
    precioProducto = list.get(0).getPrecio();
    for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getPrecio > precioProducto){
            nombreProducto = list.get(0).getNombre();
            precioProducto = list.get(0).getPrecio();
        }
    }
    system.out.println("Articulo más caro: " + nombreProducto);
}
else{
    // Error
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Para realizar la busqueda del objeto con la propiedad precio con mayor valor, lees los objetos almacenados de la lista de objetos Producto, si encuentras la coincidencia de mayor precio la almacenas en `productoMayorPrecio` :

```
//Objeto destinado para guardar producto de mayor precio.
Producto productoMayorPrecio = new Producto();
//No es necesario inicializar la propiedad ya que la propiedad tiene definido un valor entero.
//productoMayorPrecio.setPrecio(0); 

 //Itera la lista de objetos.
for (Producto producto: lista) 
    //Realiza la comparación de valor de precio entre el elemento de la lista y el producto de mayor precio.
    if(producto.getPrecio() > productoMayorPrecio.getPrecio()){ 
        //Encuentra un elemento en la lista de mayor precio.
        productoMayorPrecio = producto; //Define producto de mayor precio
     }
}

//Imprime producto con mayor precio.
System.out.println("Articulo mas caro: " + productoMayorPrecio.getNombre());
```

obteniendo como resultado:

```
Articulo mas caro: Cartuchera
```

---

Con [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/) mediante la clase [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), sin duda se puede realizar de una forma más "sencilla":

```
 Producto productoMayorPrecio = Collections.max(lista, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getPrecio()));
 System.out.println("Articulo mas caro: " + productoMayorPrecio.getNombre());
```

obteniendo como resultado:

```
 Articulo mas caro: Cartuchera
```

Comment: Agreguen explicación para el voto -1 por favor.