# Comparar elementos de un Array para encontrar el mayor

Tags: java

En el siguiente código necesito introducir dos identificadores de coches por `Scanner` y que me muestre cual es el coche que ha recorrido más kilómetros.

¿Cómo se podría hacer?.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        Coches coche = new Coches();
        // Se almacenan un numero máximo de coches (4), una vez introducidos 4 coches avisa al usuario de que no se pueden agregar más coches.
        Coches array [] = new Coches [4];
        int contador = 0;
        if (contador < array.length) {         
            System.out.println("Introduce el identificador del coche : ");          
            int identificador;
            int kilometros;
            System.out.print("Identificador :");
            identificador = teclado.nextInt();          
            System.out.print("Kilometros :");
            kilometros = teclado.nextInt();
            coche = new Coches(identificador,kilometros);         
            array [contador] = coche;
            contador++;     
            System.out.print("Coche dado de alta");
            System.out.println();
        }else{         
            System.out.print("Se ha alcanzado el maximo de coches");
        }
        // Comparar coches: el usuario introducirá dos identificadores de coches y se mostrará el coche que haya recorrido más kilometros.

//EDIT

// Comparar dos coches introduciendo sus identificadores.

System.out.print("Introduzca el primer identificador :");
System.out.print("Introduzca el segundo identificador :");

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio!, te sugiero revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas, debes ser especifico y aportar información necesaria, por ejemplo, ¿que realizr tu clase Coches?. No olvide realizar el [tour] del sitio.

Comment: primeramente estas únicamente capturando los datos de solo un Coche, debes realizar un bucle con la cantidad de autos definida, puedes usar un "while".

Comment: Existe una [pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79116/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-dos-objetos-dentro-de-un-arraylist-java) , que se podría adaptar a cualquier tipo de array de objetos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para capturar los datos de los `Coches` mediante `Scanner` y agregarlos a tu `array` debes usar `while`, ya que actualmente solo puedes crear únicamente una instancia de Coche.

En cuanto a tu clase Coches puedes agregar métodos para obtener las propiedades como el identificador y los kilometros, para realizar comparación de kilomentraje con los demás elementos.

```
public class Coches {

  int identificador;
  int kilometros;

  public Coches(){}

  public Coches(int identificador, int kilometros) {
    this.identificador = identificador;
    this.kilometros = kilometros;
  }

  public int getIdentificador(){
     return identificador;
  }

   public int getKilometros(){
     return kilometros;
  }


}
```

De esta forma puedes realizar una comparación de sus kilometros y determinar cual realizo mayor kilometraje, este sería un ejemplo basado en tu código original :

```
  public class Pruebas{

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

            Coches coche = new Coches();

            // Se almacenan un numero máximo de coches (4).

            Coches array [] = new Coches [4];

            int contador = 0;

            //if (contador < array.length) {
            while (contador < array.length) {

                System.out.println("Introduce el identificador del coche : ");

                int identificador;
                int kilometros;

                System.out.print("Identificador :");
                identificador = teclado.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Kilometros :");
                kilometros = teclado.nextInt();

                coche = new Coches(identificador,kilometros);

                array [contador] = coche;
                contador++;

                System.out.print("Coche dado de alta");
                System.out.println();

            }


                System.out.print("Se ha alcanzado el maximo de coches.\n");

                  //Busca cual realizo mayor kilometraje:

                  int maxKilometros = 0;
                  int indiceCoche = 0;
                  for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){                  
                      if(array[i].getKilometros()>maxKilometros){
                          maxKilometros = array[i].getKilometros();
                          indiceCoche = i;
                      }                   
                  }

                  System.out.print("El coche que ha recorrido más kilometros es:"  + array[indiceCoche].getIdentificador() + " Kilometros: "+ array[indiceCoche].getKilometros() +"\n");

        }
    }
```

Ejemplo :

```
Introduce el identificador del coche : 
Identificador :1
Kilometros :200
Coche dado de alta
Introduce el identificador del coche : 
Identificador :2
Kilometros :256
Coche dado de alta
Introduce el identificador del coche : 
Identificador :3
Kilometros :280
Coche dado de alta
Introduce el identificador del coche : 
Identificador :4
Kilometros :120
Coche dado de alta
Se ha alcanzado el maximo de coches
El coche que ha recorrido más kilometros es:3 Kilometros: 280
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas. En la última parte necesito que por teclado se le pidan al usuario dos identificadores de coches y compare cual de esos tiene mas kilómetros. De nuevo gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Primero una sugerencia, no definir una clase en plurar `Coches coche = new Coches();` sino en singular `Coche coche = new Coche();`

y la manera de hacerlo es recorrer el arreglo de coches e ir sacando lo kilometros de cada coche y compararlos:

```
    Coche cocheGanador;//objeto para el cohce que tenga  más kilometros
    int kilometrosCoche=0;//auxiliar de los kilometros

    for(Coche c:array){//se recorre el array de los coche para comparar
        if(c.kilometros>kilometrosCoche){//Si la variable auxiliar es menor que la del coche actual
            cocheGanador=c;//ahora el coche ganador es el cohe actual
            kilometrosCoche=c.kilometros;//lo kilometros a superar aahora son los del coche actual
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunos detalles en su código que debe tener en cuenta.

En primer lugar debería crear e `instanciar`  el objeto `Coches` dentro del `ciclo` *(while)* , esto último no lo tiene por lo tanto tal y como está su código solo se ingresará un coche al `array`.

Debería tener todo en un `while` quizá. Además por convención el nombre de las clases se escriben en Singular.  `Coche` . Para comparar y encontrar el mayor hay varias formas.  [en esta respuesta añadí algunas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/79123/12864), claro debe modificar con el campo que desea comparar.

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
// Se almacenan un numero máximo de coches (4).
Coches array [] = new Coches [4];
int contador=0,identificador,kilometros;

while (contador < array.length) { // Controlamos que no sea mayor a 4

    System.out.println("Introduce el identificador del coche : ");
    System.out.print("Identificador :");
    identificador = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Kilometros :");
    kilometros = teclado.nextInt();
    //Crear Dentro
    Coches coche = new Coches(identificador,kilometros);
    array [contador] = coche;
    contador++;
    System.out.print("Coche dado de alta");
    System.out.println();
}


Coches co = new Coches();
for (Coches coche: array) 
     if(coche.getKilometros()>co.getKilometros()) co = coche;
System.out.println("El mayor es  : " + co.getKilometros());
```